# create multiple columns in sas macro loop

Tags: sas-macro

I'm new to SAS and wondering if this is possible.
I'm using an existing table to create a wide dataset to create 36 columns, which representing months FROM 2021-2024
Each new column contain speeds. On the month he is not working, speed = 0

Existing Dataset

```
worker_name   Start_date   End_date   speed 
Jessica       01MAR22      08AUG22    8
John          04JUL23      01FEB24    9
Nathan        05JAN23      05JUN23    9
```

Dataset want:

```
worker_name   JAN   fEB   MAR   APR   MAY   JUN JUL  AUG  SEP   OCT  
Jessica        0     0    8     8      8     8   8    8    0    0    0     
John           0     0    0     0      0     0   9    9    9    9    9     
Nathan         9     9    9     9      9     9   0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: How would a macro help with this problem?  Macro code is used to generate SAS code. What SAS code do you want the macro to generate?

Answer (score 2):

Does not sound like a macro problem.

First figure out what variable names you want to use for the 36 new variables.  Then put them into an array.  Then loop by MONTH and populate the values.

```
data want;
   set have;
   array month[0:35] M0-M35 ;
   smonth = intck('month','01JAN2021'd,start_date);
   emonth = intck('month','01JAN2021'd,end_date);
   do index=0 to 35;
     if smonth <= index <= emonth then month[index]=speed;
     else month[index]=0;
   end;
run;
```